# Why should the \$\frac{e_5}{2}=rl_5(I_5)\$,not \$e_5=rl_5(I_5)\$ in the DC voltage drop?

Tags: voltage

I read something about the DC voltage drop, but there is something confusing me.

[image]

I suppose \$e_1\$ is the voltage drop between \$A\$ and \$1\$, and \$e_2\$ is the voltage drop between \$1\$ and \$2\$. \$r\$ the resistance (\$Ω\$/distance)

The thing confusing me is that why should the \$\frac{e_5}{2}=rl_5(I_5)\$, not \$e_5=rl_5(I_5)\$?

Because I think \$V=IR\$, and \$I\$ is \$I_5\$,\$R=rl_5\$,so \$e_5=rl_5(I_5)\$ makes sense, I don't know why should divide the \$e\$ by \$2\$?

I think the reason for dividing by 2 may like the formula in this website,but this website doesn't tell me why we should divide e by 2 either:

https://energypedia.info/wiki/Permissible_Voltage_Drop

Comment: Can you share the exact wording in the original source of these formulas? Particularly the part where they introduce the symbols and say what they represent (For example, somewhere it should say "\$l_n\$ is the length of the *n*th wire section, and \$e_n\$ is the [something], ...") Even if the original is in another language, there might be someone here who can read it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what's in the mind of whoever drew that diagram and wrote those equations. The diagram doesn't use the usual conventions of electrical engineering, and the equations don't use the usual symbols of electrical engineering, at least as I was taught them.

But, it's possible they are assuming that the return current for each load must return to the generator by a similarly branching path, and on a similarly sized wire, as the source current.

Then the voltage seen by each load will be reduced not just by the voltage drop in the source line, but also by the voltage drop in the return path (which we're assuming is equal to the drop in the source line).

So that the drop as estimated by the resistance of the supply wire is doubled in its effect on the voltage received by the load.

**Edit**

Here's how, if I'm guessing correctly about the meaning of your diagram, we'd represent a similar circuit with only 3 loads in a more standard schematic diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJmyyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The main difference is I've included both the supply wires and the return wires.

The point is if you want to define the term \$e_1\$ so that the voltage across load 1 is given by \$V_1 = V_s - e_1\$ (where \$V_s\$ is the voltage at the source), then you need to account for resistive loss in both the supply wire and the return wire.

Comment: what do you mean actually?i don't understand

Comment: @shineele I haven't gone to your link, but I think "The Photon" is saying that this whole question is about voltage drops along a multi-drop line. There will be a voltage drop across the wire length for the current getting out to a drop point and then also the same voltage drop across the returning wire length (for the obviously same current.) So the factor of 2 is there to account for the fact that if you have a 100' run of wire out to a drop, you really have 200' of total wire: 100' out and then 100' back.

Comment: @jonk so you mean this two means i have two line?2 AB line?

Comment: @shineele If you look at a power cord to a lamp, for example, you may be able to see the fact that there are two wires, not one, in the cord. You can also see the two prongs that plug into a socket. Every circuit has two wires going between the source of power and the device using that power. This creates a "loop" which allows outgoing current to come back to the power source. This is pretty basic, I think. You must be aware of it. If not, just look around you until it sinks in. Of course, I haven't gone to your link -- I just read The Photon's answer. So this may be my problem, not yours.